# Diameter of a set of differentiable functions

Tags: analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Given $\varepsilon>0$,  we define $H(\varepsilon)=\left\{ h\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})\ \ \mbox{with}\ \ h(0)=0\ \mbox{and}\ \left\vert h^{\prime}(t)-1\right\vert<\varepsilon\ \forall t\  \right\}$

For $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous we consider $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}{\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert}$. (Can take $+\infty$)

I would like to know if the following statement is true: Given $\gamma>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that for every $\varepsilon\in (0,\delta )$ and $h\in H(\varepsilon)$, then $d(h,\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb{R}})<\gamma$.

Note that $\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb{R}}\in H(\varepsilon)$ for each $\varepsilon>0$.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Think about linear functions in $H(\varepsilon)$!